# How to get Date and Time in Firebase Timestamp in react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

> timestamp = {seconds: 3430493049, milliseconds = 73498739873}

when I show timestamp in my website it gives us a object-like.

**Now I want to convert Data and time in this object.**

I write this line of code to show time:

[image]

And I get this error when I send a new message in my messenger app

[image]

Comment: Welcome and please include a minimum code in the body of the question and not an image. See: [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the issue you are having is that the `message` object is null.

I suggest you to the following:

- Debug and see where `message` becomes `null`

It might also be a timing issue where `message` is temporarily `null` (and will have a value later). In this case you might want to do a simple null check.

In this example I use a tenary operation to check if message have a falsy value and use `null` in case it is falsy.

```
{
    message ? new Date(message.timestamp.seconds).toLocaleTimeString("en-US") : null
}
```